# Why are MKPolyline and MKPolygon working in iOS 3.2.2 (on an iPad)?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, ios4, mapkit, polyline

As far as I can tell, technically MKPolyline and MKPolygon should ***not*** be functional/available when running on an iPad or any other device prior to iOS4.  Nevertheless, when I installed 3.2.2, on the device, and updated my build tools with the latest (non-beta) iOS 4.2 SDK, they both work just fine, along with their associated views.  What the hell?

I'm not exactly complaining here, given that the alternative would be NVPolyline and it doesn't play well with a huge number of points.  I'm just confused.  Can someone explain why these classes are available and working on the iPad?

I have not, however, had any success subclassing MKOverlayPathView on 3.2.2, even though MKPolylineView and MKPolygonView both descend from it.

Comment: So you can use MKPolyline(+View) and MKPolygon(+View) in 3.2.x ..., they work fine on the actual device, not merely the simulator.  However, once you try to subclass any of these objects, you run into the iOS4 conditions in the linking process and it falls apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs certainly claim that it was first available in 4.0, but I remember the new MapKit overhaul being part of the diff for 3.2. I think the docs just have the timeline of that update wrong.

Comment: Whatever the cause, I'm certainly hoping this doesn't flag my app for the App Store reviewers ... I know they've got disassemblers that snoop the binaries for undocumented library calls, but this might doesn't really fit with that.  I *do* know that attempts to subclass MKOverlayPathView don't work ... even though MKPolylineView is still available.  I just get the sense that this is unintended on Apple's part and that they might ding me for it ... using it on an "unsupported" configuration or somesuch.

Comment: I hear you. Don't know the answer.